# How to memoize a multi-dimensional array generation method

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming

I have a `table_data` method used to build a multi-dimensional array for a multiplication table.  The first row and column of the table are the same, with each cell containing the product for the corresponding row and column. Heres what it eventually prints:

```
    2   3   4 . . n

2   4   6   8

3   6   9  12

4   8  12  16
.
.
n
```

As you can see there are lots of duplicates that can be memoized. Here is the code for generating the multi-dimensional array:

```
def table_data(n)
  table_header(n).map do |x|
    table_header(n).map do |y|
      x*y
    end
  end
end

def table_header(n)
  @header_data ||= (1..n).to_a
end
```

The `table_data` method takes quadratic time; it is doing double the necessary work (for `x*y` and `y*x`). How can I memoize and/or alter this method to reduce the runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of reducing the runtime, it depends on whether you consider `x*y` a negligible operation or not. If you replace it with some sort of SQL query or something with a more tangible cost, then caching it would make sense. But in terms of big O complexity the dynamic variable here is the width/height of the table, e.g. number of iterations which I don't see a good way to reduce.

Anyway, to cache `x*y` you can make a helper class like this

```
class MultiplicationCache
  def initialize
    @cache = {}
  end
  def multiply(a,b)
    @cache[[a,b].sort] ||= a * b
  end
end

# usage
cache = MultiplicationCache.new
puts cache.multiply(1,2) # => 2
```

Again, it doesn't really make sense to do this unless you replace `x*y` with something that is really computationally expensive.